# SQL Query to fetch results from a table

Tags: mysql, sql

Many thanks for any help.

I have a following table consisting of 2 columns service_id and artist_id. Primary Key is (service_id, artist_id). I want to retrieve all the artists for a set of service ids.

```
Sample Table : 

service_id   artists_id
5              9
6              9
5              10
1              9
5              1
6              1
6              7
1              10
```

I tried this and it is not working as it gives all the artists who give either service id 5 or service id 6 or service id 1.

```
SELECT artists_id FROM `service_schedule` WHERE service_id IN (5, 6, 1)
```

I want artists who give service id 5 And Service Id 6 And Service Id 1. For the above sample table only artist 9 gives all the 3 services in the set (5,6,1).

So if i want to retrieve all artists who can give services with id 5 and 6 and 1. How do i write a SQL query?

Comment: Please read [ask] and elaborate on "not working".

Comment: Thank you. I will go through it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use a group by query:

```
select
  artist_id
from
  service_schedule
group by
  artist_id
having
  sum(service_id in (5,6,1))=3
```

`service_id in (5,6,1)` will be evaluated as 1 when the condition is true, and you want to check if for every artist_id the sum is 3 (all three services are given - `arist_id` and `service_id` is unique so no need to check about duplicated rows here)

Comment: Thanks for your response. It worked. Now i have added one more column. How to modify the query if i want only those artists who offer the set of services (5,6,1) and whose is_available =1. Please go through this playground  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a4a4e6/2

Comment: @MadhanShah `... from service_schedule where is_available=1 group by ...` but i think that the is_available flag should be put into another table e.g. artists... you'll then need a join

Answer (score 1):

Once try this,

```
select artist_id from table where service_id IN (5, 6) AND  
artist_id IN (select artist_id from table group by artist_id having count(*) > 1);
```

I am fetching all artist_id which has count greater than 1 and must be service_id with 5 and 6.

I hope this will help.

**EDIT**

```
select artists_id from Sample where service_id IN (5, 6, 1)  
AND  
artists_id IN (select artists_id from Sample group by artists_id  
having count(*) > 2) group by artists_id;
```

You can get, service_ids like, 5,6 or 5,6,1, you just need to take count of service ids and then `keep that value - 1` in place of 2

**EDIT**

```
select * from Sample where service_id IN (5, 6, 1, 8) and is_available = 1
AND  
artists_id IN (select artists_id from Sample where is_available = 1 group by artists_id  
having count(*) > 3) group by artists_id;
```

Comment: Mate, what are you trying to say? or tell me have you got my query first tell me, then we can talk.

Comment: I will explain question : OP is trying to ask, query should get those artist_ids which belongs to both service_ids 5 and 6 not 5 or both. it means, must be count greater than 0 right ? In short, artist_id(surely common having service id 5 & 6)

Comment: Same as I explained mate :)

Comment: thanks for playground mate! You will get answer soon for sure

Comment: hey mate, first you gave 5,6 and then 5,6,1 will these service ids dynamic ? are you using php ? and once check my edit portion. before your edit of question it was working, then you made 5,6,1 in that case you need to make count 2

Comment: Yes it will be dynamic. service_id is a set which can consist of either 1 element or more. Sure i will check it :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now i have added one more column now. How to modify the query if i want only those artists who offer the set of services (5,6,1) and whose is_available =1 . http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2a65f/2

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(s1.artists_id) FROM service_schedule s1
JOIN service_schedule s2 ON s2.service_id = s1.service_id AND s2.artists_id  <> s1.artists_id
WHERE s1.service_id IN (5, 6, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is not much clear to me but is following solution works for you if I understood it clearly.

```
select s1.service_id, s1. artists_id 
from Sample s1 inner join Sample s2
on s1.artists_id = s2.artists_id 
where s2.service_id = 5 and s1.service_id = 6
union
select s1.service_id, s1. artists_id 
from Sample s1 inner join Sample s2
on s1.artists_id = s2.artists_id 
where s2.service_id = 6 and s1.service_id = 5
```

Sample Output - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7b3a5/16

Comment: @Yousaf Modified answer check now.

Comment: Thanks for your response and time. I am very Sorry I have edited question again. Can you please try again?